# python requests only returning empty sets when scraping

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, frame

It's my first try doing programming. I'm trying to **scrape** some words by **scraping** using bs4, selenium etc...
The site I use is 'http://oulim.kr'

How can I **scrape** things inside the frameset?

this is what i have tried

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'http://oulim.kr/'

driver = webdriver.Chrome('./driver/chromedriver')
driver.get(url)

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

a = soup.select("#divAlba > table:nth-child(3) > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(5) > a > font > b")
print(a)

from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get('http://oulim.kr')
r.html.find('.tbody')
```

Comment: why don't you use BS to scrape from frames - you have url `"main.asp"` and 'http://oulim.kr' so it should use `'http://oulim.kr/main.asp'` with `BeautifulSoup`.

Comment: Selenium has `driver.switch_to.frame(...)`

Comment: FYI it’s __scraping__ and __scrape__ not scrapping or scrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Selenium` treats frames as separated pages (because it has to load it separatelly) and it doesn't search in frames. And `page_source` doesn't return `HTML` from frame.

You have to find `<frame>` and switch to correct frame `switch_to.frame(..)` to work with it.

```
frames = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('frame')
driver.switch_to.frame(frames[0])
```

---

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'http://oulim.kr/'

driver = webdriver.Chrome('./driver/chromedriver')
driver.get(url)

# --- switch frame ---

frames = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('frame')
driver.switch_to.frame(frames[0])

# --- CSS without BeautifulSoup ---

a = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#divAlba > table:nth-child(3) > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(5) > a > font > b")
print(a.text)

# --- CSS with BeautifulSoup ---

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

a = soup.select("#divAlba > table:nth-child(3) > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(5) > a > font > b")
print(a[0].text)
```